SonarQube keeps stopping from running
I want to run sonarqube but it keeps stoping by reasons that I dont know about. My sonarqube version is 10.5(I run it by ZIP not docker), Java version 17 (I already check the requirements), PostgreSQL 15.
I already created database, schema and user in postgresql, already edit the sonar.properties to write the username and password etc for the database connection. I've watch yt tutorial, ask chatGPT, read documentation, but nothings works. Can anyone help me find the solution? any help will do.
Thanks
If anyone wondering about the logs, here I give the logs
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager (file:/D:/Kodingan/sonarqube-10.5.0.89998/lib/sonar-application-10.5.0.89998.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at D:\Kodingan\sonarqube-10.5.0.89998\logs\sonarqube.log
ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly, with exit code 1
2024.05.07 22:04:46 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 1
2024.05.07 22:04:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2024.05.07 22:04:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[Web Server] is stopped
2024.05.07 22:04:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped

It seems that your elasticsearch process was interrupted by some external force. Does it work? Do you have elasticsearch? Which version?

@MuratK. I don't think I have installed the elasticsearch before, I just downloaded and unzipped the file from the Sonarqube website. Before this happened, I download the developer version of sonarqube, and it runs perfectly but I didn't know that I need the license to work with it so I change to community version, then this problem happened
